How to Set SPATIALITE_SECURITY Environment Variable in .NET for SQLite/SpatiaLite?
I’m developing a .NET application where I’m using SQLite with SpatiaLite for spatial data processing. To enable all SpatiaLite functions, I need to explicitly set the SPATIALITE_SECURITY environment variable to relaxed.
However, I’m not sure how to set this environment variable within a .NET application so that it applies correctly to SQLite/SpatiaLite.
Could someone guide me on how to do this properly in .NET?
This is what I have tried so far :
using (var connection = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source={_dbPath}")) 
{ 
    connection.Open();

    connection.EnableExtensions(true);

    SqliteCommand? command = connection.CreateCommand();

    // Load SpatiaLite extension
    command.CommandText = "SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite')";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //TRIED THIS BUT IT IS NOT WORKING
    command.CommandText = "SET  SPATIALITE_SECURITY='relaxed'";
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}


SPATIALITE_SECURITY is an environment variable, so you should set it as one. You can try using the Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable for the current process:
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SPATIALITE_SECURITY", "relaxed");

But arguably more correct approach would be to set it globally using the OS provided methods on the machine you are running the code.
